# Do portable libraries get compiled with .Net Native?

Tags: .net, win-universal-app, portable-class-library, .net-native

I'm currently using a portable library to share logic with several projects. These projects include WPF, Silverlight, Win8.1 and UWP. This library has served me well over the years and has a lot reusable code. However, with the introduction of .Net Native in UWP, I've noticed the DLL for this library is nowhere to be found. All I see is an EXE and a massive DLL in my appx:

```
MyApp.exe (~16KB)
MyApp.dll (~15MB)
```

Does .Net Native compilation also include PCLs? Does it take everything in the PCL and work its native magic?